# Window Name Incorrect

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, character-set

[image: Code for simple window instantiation]

[image: Window character set wrong]

right so I'm new to creating windows applications as I have mostly used console up until this point.
I'm confident with the ideas and understand OOP and have been using MSDN to create a simple window.

As you can see the characters used are not the same. Using MSDN I've found that the character set for LPCSTR is ANSI and I'm fairly sure VS uses Unicode so I'm not sure if that is the issue or not

If anyone can tell me why that would be great!

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20190110-00/?p=100675

Comment: Please show a [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

You are explicitly using the `A` version of functions when registering and creating your window (`RegisterClassExA()` and `CreateWindowExA()`, respectively), but you are using the `TCHAR`-based `DefWindowProc()` macro when specifying your window procedure.  You are likely compiling your project with `UNICODE` defined, thus the `DefWindowProc()` macro would map to the `DefWindowProcW()` function instead of `DefWindowProcA()`.

This mismatch will cause the behavior you are seeing, as explained in Raymond Chen's blog article:

[Why am I getting mojibake when I try to create a window?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20190110-00/?p=100675)

The solution is to use `DefWindowProcA()` explicitly instead, to match with the rest of your code logic:

```
//wc.lpfnWindowProc = DefWindowProc;
wc.lpfnWindowProc = DefWindowProcA;
```

Comment: Also relevant: [It’s okay to be contrary, but you need to be consistently contrary: Going against the ambient character set](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20211210-00/?p=106021).